# Initializing a std::shared_ptr<std::random_device>

Tags: c++

I understand that `std::random_device` is non-copyable. In this scenario, I have a `std::shared_ptr<std::random_device>` that I want to init in one of the member functions of the class. I assumed `std::move` would work. I was wrong. Would somebody explain what the 'proper' way to init the same is ?
Note : `std::random_device rng = std::make_shared<std::random_device> (std::random_device)` doesn't work either.

**Class.h**

```
class SomeClass
{
    private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::random_device> rng;
    std::shared_ptr<std::mt19937> uniform_rng;
};
```

**Class.cpp**

```
SomeClass::ctor() 
{
    //rng = std::make_shared<std::random_device>(std::random_device); -> faulty
   //rng = std::make_shared<std::random_device>(std::random_device()); -> also faulty
    uniform_rng = std::make_shared<std::mt19937> (*rng);
}
```

Comment: please include a [mcve] of the non-working code in the quesiton

Comment: added the code sample that shows how I have been trying to do it.

Comment: `*rng` ? This will cause an error for `rng` not being declared in the scope of the constructor. That error has nothing to do with `std::random_device` or shared pointers

Comment: I suppose its an edit mistake and `SomeClass` and `Class` should be the same

Comment: – 
@463035818_is_not_a_number it was a mistake.

Comment: Do you even need to maintain a pointer to the `random_device` once you've used it to initialize the `mt19937`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem confused about the syntax. This is not valid C++:

```
std::random_device rng = std::make_shared<std::random_device> (std::random_device);
```

It looks somewhat like you were trying to do this:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::random_device> rng =
      std::make_shared<std::random_device> (std::random_device{});
```

That would build a `random_device`, then call `make_shared` with it, which effectively tries to invoke a move constructor while building a new `random_device` in that shared object. That indeed only works with a copy or move constructor and is unnecessarily inefficient.

What you want is simply this:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::random_device> rng =
      std::make_shared<std::random_device>();
```

That simply constructs (via its default constructor), a new random device together with the shared pointer state. Note that whatever you pass to `make_shared` is passed to the constructor of the contained object. In this case, nothing because it is the default constructor.

### EDIT:

And for the edited question, the last line should be

```
uniform_rng = std::make_shared<std::mt19937>((*rng)());
```

to draw a single number from the random device and pass it to the mt19937 constructor. The usual caveats of initializing a mersenne twister with its enormous internal state from a single random integer apply but that is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @Homer512. this indeed works. You are right to point out that I was struggling with the syntax a bit.